# Obtain storagecontroller from virtualbox

Tags: shell, vagrant, virtualbox

im doing a shell script to automate vagrant boxes creation and im trying to obtain the boxes storagecontroller for work with the disk without errors. The debian machines have SATA Controller as disk controller but CentOS uses IDE controller. I need to grep the virtualbox virtual machines storagecontroller for use it as a variable in the script. I have tried using:

```
cat <virtualmachinename>.vbox | grep -i storagecontroller
```

But i get a extended version of information and i only need the storagecontroller.
This commands show the information in this way.

```
<StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA Controller" type="AHCI" PortCount="1" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3"></StorageController>
      <StorageController name="Floppy Controller Controller" type="I82078" PortCount="1" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true"/>
</StorageControllers>
```

In this case i need to grep "Sata Controller".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done using this command:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo <machine-name> --machinereadable | grep storagecontrollername0 | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed 's/\"//g'
```